# Save axios response to state react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I am trying to save the response I get from Axios to state using hooks.  However, whenever I attempt to use the hook, the  component continues to re-render an unlimited number of times.

```
const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);

const getUserOrders = async () => {
        await API.getOrders(window.sessionStorage.id)
            .then(res => setOrders(res.data.ordersArr))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
useEffect(() => {
        if (logged_in) {
            getUserOrders();
        } else {
            window.location.href = "/login";
        }
}, [orders])
```

If I console log res.data.ordersArr instead of using the setOrders hook, I am able to see the expected data.  When I use the hook, it keeps re-rendering.

Comment: why is `orders` in your `useEffect` dependency array?

Comment: My thought was it wouldn't continue to update if the orders did not change.

Comment: everytime you call `setOrders` they change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of things you need to refactor

1. your React Hook useEffect has  dependency `orders` which will re render unlimited times
2. `.then` after await dont make any sense , either get rid of async / await or include the promise callback

```
    const getUserOrders = () => {
            API.getOrders(window.sessionStorage.id)
                .then(res => setOrders(res.data.ordersArr))
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
    useEffect(() => {
            if (logged_in) {
                getUserOrders();
            } else {
                window.location.href = "/login";
            }
    }, [])
```

Comment: As much as it's correct to point out the unnecessary use of `await`, it wouldn't have an effect on the result, the fix is purely just removing `orders` from the dependency list of the `useEffect` call.

Answer (score 1):

Your `useEffect` hook will re-run each time the `orders` state changes, when your `useEffect` hook runs you fetch data from the API and then set the `orders`. This in turn then triggers a render with a new value for `orders` thus invalidating the `useEffect` call and causing it to fire again which ultimately leads to the infinite loop.

You simply want to force the `useEffect` to run once by passing an empty dependency list `useEffect(..., [])`

Comment: @CB721 do you really need a complete code example? It's literally a case of replacing `[orders]` with `[]`.